# Robocopy - Overwrite all files unless file in destination is newer

Tags: windows-server-2012, backup-restoration, robocopy

The title pretty much sums it up.

I had restored a file share recently from a backup.  Come to find out after about a day of users in production we started to notice some files were corrupt.  Pulling those files from the backup again shows that the backups are in fact intact.  However, users are modifying files going forward.

Using robocopy,  can I overwrite all files in this share skipping newer files on the destination?  In other words, I basically want to recopy everything unless the user has made changes to a file on the share.

The /is flag seems intriguing, but unsure if it will overwrite a file with a newer timestamp.

And insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

/xo Excludes older files.

That’s what you need.

Comment: How would excluding older files prevent a new file in the destination from being overwritten?  Wouldn't `/XO` result in the opposite of what's being requested, resulting in new files being overwritten?  Shouldn't `/XN` be utilized, either with or without `/MON`?

Comment: as per the link above:    /xo excludes older source files.  So  it is correct to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize:

- **`/MON:1`**: **MON**itor source; run again when more than `n` changes seen
- **`/XN`**: e**X**clude **N**ewer files

```powershell
robocopy D:\Source\Sync \\ShareName\Sync /TBD /E /XN /MON:1 /LOG+:"\\ShareName\Sync\Logs\Sync.log" /V /TEE /TS /XD Logs
```

The following script will monitor the source directory for any changes and log whenever a file is copied to the destination directory.

**Script: `File-Sync.cmd`**

```powershell
::
                 ::[[---  RoboCopy File Sync Script ---]]::

::=========================================================================

@echo off

:: Parameters ::
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: Set Variables ::

  :: Date:
     set Date=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%

  :: Time:

     :: Hour:
        set Hour=%time:~0,2%
        if "%hour:~0,1%" == " "  set HH=0%hour:~1,1%

     :: Minute:
        set MM=%time:~3,2%

     :: Seconds
        set SS=%time:~6,2%

     set Dtime=%HH%%mm%%ss%

  :: Destination:
     set Dest=\\ShareName\Sync

  :: Log:
     set LogDir=\\Sharename\Sync\Logs

  :: Source:
     set Src=D:\Source\Sync

  :: RoboCopy:

     :: Log:
        set Log=/V /TEE /TS /LOG:"%LogDir%\%date%_%dtime%.log"

     :: Options:
        set Options=/TBD

     :: What to Copy:
        set What=/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:DAT /E /XD Logs /XN /MON:1

     :: Save Job:
        set Save=/SAVE:C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\File-Sync


:: Sync ::
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------
RoboCopy %Src% %Dest% %What% %Options% %Log% %Save%
```

- **Date & Time:** *(Locale dependent)*

  - **`%date%`**:  Outputs a date in the following format: `yyyy.MM.dd`
  - **`%dtime%`**: Outputs time in the following format: `HHmmss`
- **Directories:**

  - **`%Dest%`**: Destination Directory
  - **`%LogDir%`**: Log Directory
  - **`%Src%`**: Source Directory
- **RoboCopy:**

  - **`%log%`**: Logging Options, outputs a log file in the following format `YYYY.MM.DD_HHMMSS.log`

    - **`/V`**: Produce Verbose output, showing skipped files
    - **`/TEE`**: Output to console window, as well as the log file

      - *Helpful if needing to run from a terminal occassionally*
    - **`/TS`**: Include source file Time Stamps in the output
    - **`/LOG:`**: Output status to LOG file (overwrite existing log)

      - *Will never overwrite, provided `%dtime%` is included*
  - **`%options%`**: RoboCopy options

    - **`/TBD`**: wait for share names **T**o **B**e **D**efined
  - **`%what%`**: What to copy

    - **`/COPY:DAT`**: what to **COPY** for files (default is `/COPY:DAT`)

      - Copy Flags: **D**=Data, **A**=Attributes, **T**=Timestamps
    - **`/DCOPY:DAT`**: Same as above, except for directories
    - **`/E`**: copy subdirectories, including **E**mpty ones
    - **`/XD`**: E**X**clude **D**irectories matching given names/paths

      - *Required if Log Directory is stored in the Source directory*
    - **`/XN`**: e**X**clude **N**ewer files
    - **`/MON:1`**: **MON**itor source; run again when more than n changes seen
  - **`/SAVE`**: **SAVE** parameters to the named job file

    - *Outputs job file to: `C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\File-Sync.rcj`*

**Run Script Silently: `NoShell-RoboCopy.vbs`**

```vbs
'
            '::[[---  Run RoboCopy File Sync Silently  ---]]::'
'=========================================================================

If WScript.Arguments.Count >= 1 Then
    ReDim arr(WScript.Arguments.Count-1)
    For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1
        Arg = WScript.Arguments(i)
        If InStr(Arg, " ") > 0 Then Arg = """" & Arg & """"
      arr(i) = Arg
    Next

    RunCmd = Join(arr)
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run RunCmd, 0, True
End If
```

- Execute:

  ```powershell
  wscript "C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\NoShell-RoboCopy.vbs" "C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\File-Sync.cmd"
  ```

**Task Schedule: `File-Sync.xml`** *(runs 30s after user login)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2018-10-25T07:45:58.952588</Date>
    <Author>Windows\User</Author>
    <Description>Task to synchronize local disk to network backup</Description>
    <URI>\Backup\Network File Sync</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Delay>PT30S</Delay>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>%WinDir%\system32\wscript.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>"C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\NoShell-RoboCopy.vbs" "C:\ProgramData\Scripts\Robocopy\File-Sync.cmd"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: If down voting an answer, please provide the reason why, else the answer can't have whatever is wrong corrected.

Comment: An issue might be that the output of `%date%` and `%time%` is locale-dependent. Very annoying from my perspective as it easily breaks scripts.

Comment: @PaulB. I wasn't aware of that, thanks for letting me know =] Is there a solution to this, or should I simply remove those variables from the script?

Answer (score 0):

*Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy*

- `/xn`   Source directory files newer than the destination are excluded from the  copy.
- `/xo`   Source directory files older than the destination are excluded from the copy.

So, in direct response to the opening question, /xo is the option to avoid overwriting newer files in destination.

NOTE: ROBOCOPY options have sometimes funny interactions. Always test before running on actual files. During testing this example I managed to score no fewer than two weird situations.

Example (tested on Windows 10):

`robocopy test-source test-destination /E /XO /Z /R:5 /W:5 /TBD /NP /V /MT:16`

- `/Z` Copies files in restartable mode.
- `/ZB` Copies files in restartable mode. If file access is denied, switches to backup mode. Requires Backup and Restore Files user rights.
- `/E` Copies subdirectories. This option automatically includes empty directories.
- `/XO` REQUESTED OPTION. Do not overwrite newer files in destination.
- `/R:5` Retry 5 times to copy a file.
- `/W:5` Wait 5 seconds before retrying to copy a file.
- `/TBD` Specifies that the system will wait for share names to be defined (retry error 67).
- `/NP` Do not display progress.
- `/V` Produces verbose output, and shows all skipped files.
- `/MT:16` Improve performance by using multithreaded copies (use it with /LOG to redirect output to file).